# WordPress Gutenberg Signal on Block Alignment Change

Tags: block-editor, select

Is there any selector I can use to subscribe to an block alignment change? I am writng a custom block that needs to do some actions when the user changes the block alignment to 'wide' or 'full'. I browsed the whole [Data Module Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/data/) and found no such.

Comment: A more useful question that's technically the same question would be how to run code when attributes on blocks change. The solution would be the same, but it would be a more helpful answer, and easier to answer too. With that in mind, a selector is the wrong approach. A selector will tell you what data is, not when it changes, so your proposed solution is not going to work, once you get a selector based answer you'll run straight into a brick wall requiring a refactor

Comment: Also, are you specifically asking about the current block? Or arbitrary blocks? Aka all blocks, or other blocks that are not the block the current component? Also what are these _actions_? There's a very high chance that this too is an attempt to do something that you shouldn't be doing because that's not how it's meant to work. E.g. a lot of people are unaware of `useEffect` or the data store, and do terrible things like making raw HTTP requests in their block edit components which causes problems and unexpected bugs. Provide as much context as you can

Comment: Well thanks, you already helped me a lot. I had a bug in my thinking, that was, not realizing that the Toolbar Buttons for wide and full alignment really are changing block attributes. I was confused because it was not me coding them like other toolbar controls.